# How to solve $y'=\arctan(x+y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The differential equation is $$y'=\arctan(x+y)$$$$y(0)=1$$
I tried to resolve it by change of variable $z=x+y$ and I got the following
$$\int \frac{dz}{\arctan(z)+1} = x+c$$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$.
However I cannot resolve the integral, I also tried to put $$x=\arctan(x+y)$$ But it didn't lead me anywhere. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

setting $$x+y=u$$ then we have $$1+y'=u'$$ and you have to solve $$u'=\arctan(u)+1$$ which is easy to solve
and then i would solve the equation $$x=\arctan(x+y)$$ for $$y$$

Comment: This is what OP did. The question is about making further progress.

Comment: Asked for $\int\frac{dx}{1+\arctan x}$, WolframAlpha says that no integral is known with elementary functions (and it considers as elementary many more functions than usual).

Comment: yes i think it is true, there is no elementary solution

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner This is exactly what he said :) You have used $u$ instead of $z$.

Comment: thank you for your help, but the real problem is the integral i can't find a solution for it. Is the condition y(0)=1 of any help?

Comment: i will try it give me time